# Can all nonlinear groups be represented by integral transforms?

Tags: group-theory, integral-transforms, infinite-groups

This is an extension to the infinite-dimensional case of the usual question, "are all groups linear".

Given that nonlinear groups exist, can such groups always be represented as a group of integral transforms -- informally, an "infinite dimensional matrix multiplication"? Or do there still exist groups that cannot be written in linear form, even given an infinity of dimensions to work with?

Comment: It's much easier to see that all groups can be represented by infinite matrices - every group $G$ has a regular representation on its own group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$.